# Python-Write a statement if there is a certain character in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I finally was helped and was able to count how many specific characters there are in a file, I am trying top enhance the code by writing/printing a line if there is a specific character in a file here is part of the code that I have that is suppose to do that, no errors given, just doesn't work. Any suggestions on approaching this issue?

```
atom_count = len(set('OHCN').intersection(chain.from_iterable(f1)))
  s = s.replace('ntyp = 11', 'ntyp = {}'.format(atom_count))
  f = open(filename, 'w')
  f.write(s)
  f.flush()
  f.close()

  linenum = f.readLines()

  if {} == 'H':
       f.write('Hydrogen') + linenum[22]
  elif {} == 'C':
        f.write('Carbon') + linenum[23]
  elif {} == 'N':
        f.write('Nitrogen') + linenum[24]
  elif {} == 'O':
        f.write('oxygen') + linenum[25]
```

Comment: What do you think `{}` does?

Comment: I thought it is the character range that I set in atom_count, assuming I am incorrect there

Comment: `{}` is an empty dictionary, so it will never be equal to a string.

Comment: how would I declare the 4 variables in the dictionary? something like this maybe: a = {OHNC}, and do something like this: for lines in filname: then have the if statements? is there another way that I can use the itertools.chain method that I have up there to make file easier?

Comment: Why do you want to use itertools.chain? don't you just want to write out a string if 'H'/'O'/'N'/'C' are in the current line?

Comment: @sheeptest, No, I want to write out a string or write to the file, if itertools.chain method finds one or more of the chars, then for each char found print the string

Comment: for each char? or each line containing the char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise a dictionary to provide the lookup info you require, then refer to that after getting the atoms (untested example):

```
atom_lookup = {
    'H': ('Hydrogen', 22),
    'C': ('Carbon', 23),
    # etc....
}

with open('ohcn_file') as f1, open('other_file') as f2:
    atoms_present = atom_lookup.viewkeys() & chain.from_iterable(f1)
    f2_lines = list(f2)
    for atom in atoms_present:
        atom_name, atom_lineno = atom_lookup[atom]
        atom_line = f2_lines[atom_lineno]
        # do something with atom_name and atom_line...
```

Comment: Thank you! had to do some modifications, but worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues at work here.

First, as others have pointed out, `{}` is an empty dictionary and will never be equal to anything but another empty dictionary.  Curly braces have a different meaning within a string than they do in code.  In a string `'Hello, {}'.format('World')` will do what you expect, but outside of a string, it represents a dictionary data type.

Second, the order of your file operations is incorrect.  You should open the file, read its contents, then close the file.

Third, you need to iterate over the file contents with something, such as a for loop.